# How can I process checkbox items from an Oracle APEX report?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am not an experienced APEX developer, hence this problem: I have a report with a few columns, the first one displays a checkbox whose value is the column ID for the row record,  and I need to run a pl/sql function for each row checked but I have had no luck...

The relevant columns' SQL looks something like this (trimmed for the sake of simplicity):

```
SELECT
  apex_item.checkbox(1, p.ticket_id,'UNCHECKED') "Add",
  p.ticket_id,
  UPPER(SUBSTR(p.status_code, 1, 3)) status,
  p.last_update
FROM problems p
... etc.
```

The first column is set to render as a "Simple Checkbox" and its got #TICKET_ID# for its List Of Value parameters. I have a submit button set to just submit the page, and I have created a process that runs "On submit - after computations and validations" whose executed code is the following PL/SQL:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i in 1..APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01.COUNT LOOP
    BEGIN
      IF APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i) IS NOT NULL THEN
      run-some-procedure-function(
        parameter_one => APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01(i),
        parameter_two => :SOME_VALUES_ID,
        parameter_three => :F_AU_ID
      );
      END IF;
      EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

When I run this App, mark some checkboxes, and hit the submit button I end up with an error message and a weird URL ending:

[image: APEX Error on submit with checkbox values]

Any ideas and/or suggestions are welcome, even a different approach to my problem (I just need to stick to checkboxes because I need that) is accepted.

Comment: What is the plsql error showing up in your webserver logs?

Comment: You mention an LOV. Is this LOV defined on the ticket_id field? Try running the page with debug too, see if you can spot the error there and get back to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips to track down the cause:

1. Check the branch after you hit the Submit button. Do you branch to the same page or a different page?
2. If the branch is okay, then as part of testing comment run-some-procedure-function in the process and see, just to make sure the function is not the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks, I carefully looked into the processing sections and figured out I was not referencing the checkboxed values correctly.